# cssClass appears as not defined

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I don't think it's critical since it works. But I was just wondering why sometimes in html it looks like a CssClass doesn't exist, when it does..
[image]

and when I run the application all the css data from that class is in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an issue with Visual Studio's intellisense, I've come across this a few times myself. I don't think its anything to be concerned with.

Restarting your software, and reopening the application should fix the problem.

However, it might depend on how you're including the stylesheet in your pages. If you are including this programatically, then Visual Studio won't be able to understand this, and therefore won't pick up on the styles in it's intellisense, it just picks up on the styles from StyleSheet's included in the `head` tag as `link` elements.

Comment: Agree, if the css displays fine within the browser, don't concern yourself with the VS2010 css intellisense, which in my opinion is the most useless feature of VS especially with large/complex css files with lots of classes. You may find that VS2010 crashes as soon as you type `class="` if you find this happens, best thing to do is to quickly tab twice when the class attribute appears in intellisense.

Comment: Noted. thanks a lot guys! yeah, I didn't think it was important, just wondered why :)